# Canvas.setLeft(Ellipse1, x) doesn't work

Tags: wpf, vb.net

So, i have an ellipse defined in xaml before running the program. And at some point of the program i want to position the ellipse at the beginning coordinates. I tried:

```
Ellipse1.setValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, x)
```

and didn't work. I tried then:

```
Canvas.setLeft(Ellipse1, x)
```

but still doesn't work. Even the `Ellipse1.Width = x` doesn't work. I know that this is a very unspecific question and i don't expect the solution right away but if you'd only have any idea why the code doesn't work would help a lot.

Comment: Is the ellipse directly inside a Canvas ?

Comment: Yes it is. Is that the problem?

Comment: no this isn't the problem.  Maybe you should post the relevant part of the XAML and code